# Does MathQuill support the \nmid LaTeX command?

Tags: javascript, latex, mathquill

When I try to show that 3 does not divide 4 in LaTeX like this, `3 \nmid 4`, it does not display what I need. However, `\mid` works correctly.

`mid` working correctly:

[image: mid working correctly]

`nmid` not working:

[image: nmid not working]

I do a google search on is there a configuration to enable or disable this but didn't find anything.

My configurations:

```
    var mathField = MQ.MathField(mathFieldSpan, {
        spaceBehavesLikeTab: true, // configurable
        // autoCommands: 'pi theta sqrt sum',
        autoOperatorNames: 'sin cos',
        substituteTextarea: function() {
            return document.createElement('textarea');
        },
        handlers: {
            edit: function () { // useful event handlers
                latexSpan.textContent = mathField.latex(); // simple API
            },
            enter: function () {
                // addMathField();
            },
        }
    });
```